# How to convert a string to an expression in Microsoft Visual Basic for Application (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I am working on a report at work - and I have several products that I want to be analyzing i.e. the Tons offloaded etc. I am getting these products from the listbox, for multiple product selection, I am converting to string as below

```
    Dim strToArr As Variant, prdctFcsTest As Boolean
    strToArr = Split(prdct_focus, ";") 'prdct_focus - being the string of selected products from listbox
```

then join it like below so that I can convert it to an expression for evaluation

```
 If UBound(strToArr) > 1 Then _
   prdctFcsTest = Application.Evaluate(Join(strToArr, "=" & wkrsht.Name & " OR ") & "=" & wkrsht.Name) _
 Else _
   prdctFcsTest = LCase(Trim(wkrsht.Name)) = Trim(LCase(prdct_focus))
```

So far for a single product analysis its working perfectly, but for multi-products analysis, thats where I am stuck with the Logic. To convert the unravelled the Join statement above to an expression

```
Application.Evaluate(Join(strToArr, "=" & wkrsht.Name & " OR ") & "=" & wkrsht.Name)
```

Comment: `Application.Evaluate` evaluates Excel formulas, not VBA code. Why do you want to use it in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. This is what I wanted, to convert string (see last code) to expression.

Comment: Would help to show the type of expression you want to create and explain what it's purpose is.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Like you need to Loop through all the List in your Array to Pass it to Application.Evaluate Function. I suggest you reconstruct your if statement as below:

```
If UBound(strToArr) > 1 Then 
  'For Looping through your Array List; 
  'The first item on the List can be referenced as strToArr(1),second item strToArr(2) and so forth
  'But since your List will vary anytime you must use an "i" to loop through listbox
  'Until you reach the Maximum (UBound) which signifies the end of the list.
  Dim i as integer
  For i= 1 to UBound(strToArr)
  
  prdctFcsTest = Application.Evaluate(Join(strToArr(i), "=" & wkrsht.Name & " OR ") & "=" & wkrsht.Name) Else prdctFcsTest = LCase(Trim(wkrsht.Name)) = Trim(LCase(prdct_focus))
  next i   'This will go back to the array for next item on the list
End If    'End of Checking if strArr is greater than 1.
```

Comment: The question has a score of -3 at the time of my review of the answer. This may be an answer but the question will be closed or deleted shortly.